# In oracle XE, what is the difference between the autobackup and backupset direcories?

Tags: backup, oracle-xe

I am learning oracle db, and in Oracle XE, there are autobackup and backupset directories under flash_recovery_area/XE. In both directories, there are bkp files under the datestamped directoy.

What is the difference between the bkp files in  autobackup and backupset  directories?  In other words, what is the difference between the autobackup and backupset direcories? Thank you very much.

Comment: There are several questions within this question which should be separate entries if they are not already on dba.se

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I edited the question.  Thank you.

Comment: I did some search and what I found is as follows. "backupset will contain the RMAN backup files. autobackup will contain the controlfile autobackup."  Is this correct? Does that mean the autobackup directory will contain only the control file and not the data file backup?  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`AUTOBACKUP`, by default, contains automatic backups of the controlfile and the spfile (if the database has one), if the `AUTOBACKUP` feature is enabled.

```
rman target /
show all;
```

There you should see:

```
CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP OFF# default
```

Or `ON`, if it is configured. With `AUTOBACKUP` enabled, the controlfile will be automatically backed up on backup operations, and on changing the structure of the database (e.g creating a new tablespace, adding a new datafile). In 10g it is performed immediately after changing the structure, starting with 11.2, it is performed a bit later (Controlfile Autobackup Deferral), allowing the execution of multiple structure changes without creating an unnecessary controlfile autobackup for each action.

`BACKUPSET`, well, that is where all other backups go, by default. Backups of the datafiles, archivelogs and controlfile and spfile backups if `AUTOBACKUP` is disabled, or created explicitly.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.  So, I understand that the AUTOBACKUP directory never contains any datafiles and archivelogs and has only the controlfile and spfile depending on how it is configured. Thank you.